# Worklight integration to IBM Forms

Tags: forms, ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to integrate Worklight hybrid apps to IBM Forms ?

Or is it at least possible to invoke a remote web page url during (not startup) app usage and return to the app on completion using some page events.

Btw, I'm aware of the Forms -> Portal -> Worklight integration. But that too seems to be when the entire app is just a container for the Portal web application.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is supposed to happen after you "invoke the remote web page", so w/out knowing this I can think of right now two approaches:

1. Use [Cordova's InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) to open an external URL w/out exiting the application
2. See this training module: [Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_06_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf) ([sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip))

Comment: Hi Idan, I basically need to open a web form from IBM Forms...fill it up and submit, and return back to the app where I left.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to include/launch server side content in a Worklight app.  The challenge is always communication between the Worklight app and the server side app.

Putting the server side content in an IFrame allows message passing between the server based app and the worklight app, but IFrames work very badly on mobile platforms.  You end up with all sorts of scrolling, layout and scaling headaches.

If direct communication isn't required, then there are a number of options that are fairly easy to implement.  I have a blog post looking at different methods of including server side content in a Worklight app [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/including_external_content_in_a_worklight_application1?lang=en).

Comment: Hi David, Went through the article, great piece of work. I'm interested in invoking the server page during a button click (of a standard WL hybrid app), and be able to interact with it. I noticed the interaction is part of your upcoming article...any insight ?

Comment: Interaction is tricky.  If you use iFrame, then you can use addEventListener/dispatchEvent to communicate between the windows.  If you are using inAppBrowser, then the app in the browser can send information to the WL app by navigating to a URL with properties.  The WL app can be listening for loadstart events, and can read the properties of the URL.  Unfortunately, better communication with InAppBrowser will have to wait for Cordova 3 (WL 6.1), which has imlplemented executeScript on the InAppBrowser object.